# Cannot connect to Google Cloud Run sidecar container via localhost

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am attempting to run a web container that talks to a postgresql container via Google Cloud Run.

Here is a snippet from my yaml configuration for the service:

```
spec:
      containerConcurrency: 80
      timeoutSeconds: 300
      serviceAccountName: 328305070564-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
      containers:
      - name: invidious-1
        image: ceramicwhite/invidious:build-3450896@sha256:4b90f6123c14a140c0c5aa39fbb1b49e520832b68a2d5606e11062592b7015cd
        ports:
        - name: http1
          containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: INVIDIOUS_CONFIG
          value: |
            db:
              dbname: db-name
              user: my-username
              password: super-secret
              host: localhost
              port: 5432
            check_tables: true
            external_port: 3000
            captcha_enabled: false
            admins: ["umbrel"]
            default_user_preferences:
              feed_menu: ["Trending", "Subscriptions", "Playlists"]
              default_home: Trending
            hmac_key: "${APP_SEED}"
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 512Mi
        startupProbe:
          timeoutSeconds: 240
          periodSeconds: 240
          failureThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: 3000
      - name: postgres1
        image: postgres:13.7@sha256:03652c675ae177af98ddd50f9f4b4b2cf8ad38d0e116aa68fe670fbc2cf250fc
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: db-name
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: my-username
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: super-secret
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 1Gi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: in-memory-1
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/
      volumes:
      - name: in-memory-1
        emptyDir:
          medium: Memory
          sizeLimit: 2G
  traffic:
  - percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
```

Based on this, I would expect my invidious container to be able connect to to my postgresql container via `localhost:5432`. That jives with the documentation I read here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-multi-container-deployments

However, instead the invidious container fails to start. I get an error:

```
DEFAULT 2023-11-30T00:11:19.947768Z Caused by: Error connecting to 'localhost:5432': Connection refused (Socket::ConnectError)
  {
    "textPayload": "Caused by: Error connecting to 'localhost:5432': Connection refused (Socket::ConnectError)",
    "insertId": "6567d327000e76387751e45a",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "complete-agency-406616",
        "service_name": "invidious",
        "location": "us-central1",
        "revision_name": "invidious-00017-zms",
        "configuration_name": "invidious"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-11-30T00:11:19.947768Z",
    "labels": {
      "container_name": "invidious-1",
      "instanceId": "0087599d428e073fef5c3ed8cac751f0df4ddf6710c3884e7ba9212319f7d82d07ac9ef1b0ccb73104a618d398bdb8135c6cf22faba200e7dcea2130a6f14f90eea2e64c"
    },
    "logName": "projects/complete-agency-406616/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-11-30T00:11:19.975329453Z"
  }
```

I've also tried other values in place of localhost with the same failure, including:

- `127.0.0.1`
- `postgres1`

How am I supposed to reach my sidecar container from my ingress container? I would rather not set up a costly VPC since my goal is to remain free-tier for this service.

Comment: I don't think you have a connection problem. I think something happened with PostgreSQL and it is not running. Do the logs have details about PostgreSQL startup and status?

Comment: The last log I see is `2023-12-01 17:59:51.019 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections`. So it looks like Postgres is up and running as it should

Comment: When I use the heuristic domain name https://<servicename>-<identifier>.run.app, I don't see the connection error anymore, but it seems to just hang there and invidious container does not start

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for long, still don't know what's wrong. But manage to make it work.

It might be linked to exposing or not ports in Dockerfiles.

What I did is to copy the demo from google codelabs https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/create-cloud-run-service-sidebar-localhost-volume-mount?hl=en#3

The codelab do work, then i transformed my ingress and sidecar with git submodules including my code. Except! I kept the Dockerfiles from the demo. Keeping the service and CI files from the demo too.

Now the app is working well but i couldn't say precisely how to fix the issue. Just copy the exact dockerfiles, service and CI files.

Best